# Is it possible to setup Wake on WAN while not having access to ARP tables?

Tags: networking, router, wake-on-lan

My ISP does not provide me with access to the ARP Tables on my ISP provided Modem Router, this means that I cannot stop the ARP tables from being flushed (not sure if that's the right term) every 5 minutes from my Modem Router after the computer I intend to turn on shuts down.

So far I have tried: Setting up a static IP on the target PC, setting a DMZ for the target PC, creating a DDNS for my router, port-fowarding for both TCP and UTP for port 7 and 9 and using a tplink router with proper IP and MAC binding (this one also failed because with the tplink router in the chain I was not able to use either WOL or WOW at all)

Question is, how can I setup WOW properly if I do not have access to the ARP tables? The only extra equiment I currently own is the tplink router, with that being said I do not know how to set it up properly for this as I explained above.

Comment: @FrankThomas The problem is as follows, in steps so it's easier to understand:
1 - I turn on the PC through the power button or WOL
2 - I turn it off again to test turning it on through WOW
3 - I managed to turn it on through WOW so I turn it off again and wait for 5 minutes
4 - I can no longer use WOW as it will not go through, WOL works fine
Essentially I can only use use WOW for 5 minutes after shutdown, otherwise it won't work at all

Comment: I probably should've been clearer about what I meant.

Essentially I want to use Wake On Wan to turn on a computer on my network, just how you use Wake On Lan to turn on a computer on a local network I've been trying to do that with Wake On Wan to some success. That's the 5 minutes I was referring to, Wake On Wan works for five minutes with count down starting from when the computer has shut down, after that only Wake On Lan or the physical power button work. After research I was led to believe that I had to bind the computer's IP to its MAC through ARP.

Comment: ok, I don't know anything about the Wake-on-WAN protocols, so I will delete my comments to clean up your thread. I do recommend you clarify your question. best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't use "Wake on magic packet" in this situation, as the router needs to know the destination MAC address *somehow.* (In other words, the feature that you don't have access to *is* literally the feature that would allow you to do this properly.)

Though the MAC address in packet headers doesn't strictly need to be the computer's own address – when WoL is used locally, the packets are more commonly sent to the "broadcast" MAC address instead, which will reach the computer's network card all the same. So you can try adding a port-forward rule with 192.168.1.**255** (i.e. the last address of your subnet) as the destination IP, but this usually doesn't work as the router just refuses to send packets to the broadcast IP address.

Finally, you could try using "Wake on pattern" which will make *the ARP query itself* wake the system from sleep (on Windows – uncheck the "Only allow management stations to wake…" box) but this will likely result in the system waking up far more often than expected.

---

TCP is never used for WoL "magic packets" since the target computer can't really establish a TCP connection when it's still asleep. (Though the aforementioned wake-on-pattern can allow the TCP handshake itself to wake the system, at which point you no longer need to send a "magic packet" anymore, but again this may result in unwanted wakeups.)

Comment: That makes sense, without the access to the configuration I need I'm stuck here. I'll probably have to figure out some other way to do this, maybe a raspberry pi or something similar to that. Either way thank you a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my specific problem by following this guide on Tom's Hardware Forum: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/the-ultimate-modem-router-setup-thread.1303081/

And more specifically PPPoA config in there.